# How to add a new html element to a page after a background process has finished in express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a video converter app with express. The user will click a button on an html page to start the conversion. The conversion is done on the server in a background process. How can I update the html page after conversion is finished ('end' event) to show a download button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to utilise server sent events, using a channel on the server side and subscribe to any messages on the client side.

Some example implementations could be [eventsource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventsource) or [sse-channel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse-channel) node package.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.